# If touch is in CCSprite bounds? Cocos2d v3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uitouch, ccsprite

I am trying to create a simple helper method to detect whether a UITouch is within a CCSprite's bounds with this method:

```
- (BOOL)containsTouchLocation:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint p = [self convertToNodeSpace:touch.locationInWorld];
    CGRect r = self.boundingBox;
    return CGRectContainsPoint(r, p);
}
```

It seems like it should work in retrospect but it just returns "NO" even though the touch is clearly in a sprite on the screen. Is there something I am doing wrong here? I am using Cocos2d v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that `boundingBox` is the analog of `frame` and not `bounds`. Therefore `r` is in coordinate space of the `parent` of the node and `p` in coordinate space of the node itself.

If you *know* that node has a parent you can calculate `p` in parents coordinate space:

```
CGPoint p = [self.parent convertToNodeSpace:touch.locationInWorld];
// You can also use a shorthand [touch locationInNode: self.parent];
```

Or instead you could get `r` as the `bounds` rect instead of the `frame`

```
// notice that it is `contentSizeInPoints` and not `contentSize`
CGRect r = { .origin = CGPointZero, .size = self.contentSizeInPoints };
```

But either way the `CCNode` now also has `hitAreaExpansion` which you might want to take into account:

```
r = CGRectInset(r, -self.hitAreaExpansion);
```

Or instead of doing all this you could use the `hitTestWithWorldPos:` method, default implementation of which tests whether given world location is within bounds of the node +/- `hitAreaExpansion`.